# php sql multi bind_param

Tags: php, mysql

so far I've come to this.

My goal is to be able to apply optional search filters such as a.chainid and a.branchid if needed, for that to happen I need dynamic bind_param.

The code seems to be fine, but in fact it's not working for some reason.

Care to tell me what's wrong?

The fetch returns me nothing instead of 5 rows that should.

Thanks in advance

```
$sql = "SELECT a.COUPONID, a.TRUSTANDUSEID FROM `custom_redemptions` a WHERE a.couponid = 3";

    $types = '';
    $params = array(&$types);

    if ($branchid != null) {
        $sql .= "AND a.branchid = ?";
        $types .= 's';
        $params[] = $branchid;
    }
    if ($chainid != null) {
        $sql .= "AND a.chainid = ?";
        $types .= 's';
        $params[] = $chainid;
    }

    if ($stmt = $this->dbCon->prepare($sql)) {
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($couponid, $trustanduseid);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) { echo $couponid; }
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Comment: Try to delete 'a' before Where in sql statement.

Comment: Still not working :/ The problem should be about call_user_func_array

Answer (score 0):

This solution might help you

```
$sql = "SELECT a.COUPONID, a.TRUSTANDUSEID FROM `custom_redemptions` a WHERE a.couponid = 3";

    $types = '';
    $params = array(&$types);

    if ($branchid != null) {
        $sql .= " AND a.branchid = ?";
        $types .= 's';
        $params[] = $branchid;
    }
    if ($chainid != null) {
        $sql .= " AND a.chainid = ?";
        $types .= 's';
        $params[] = $chainid;
    }

    if ($stmt = $this->dbCon->prepare($sql)) {
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($couponid, $trustanduseid);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) { echo $couponid; }
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally what was needed was &$chainid instead of $chainid.

Spent 8 hours researching about it. LOL