# php sql dynamic bind_param issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have 3 elements in the $params array.

When I use `$branchid` or `$chainid` alone they work fine, but when I use both of them it doesn't work, and I'm almost 100% positive it has to do with "&"(references) when combining.

Any ideas to make it work?

1st `var_dump` (single filter) (THIS ONE WORKS)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  &string(1) "s"
  [1]=>
  &string(3) "405"
}
```

2nd var_dump (both filters) (DOESN'T WORK)

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  &string(2) "ss"
  [1]=>
  &string(3) "329"
  [2]=>
  &string(3) "405"
}


$types = '';
        $params = array(&$types);

        if ($branchid != null) {
            $sql .= "AND a.branchid = ?";
            $types .= 's';
            $params[] = &$branchid;
        }
        if ($chainid != null) {
            $sql .= "AND a.chainid = ?";
            $types .= 's';
            $params[] = &$chainid;
        }

var_dump($params);

// SQL //
        if ($stmt = $this->dbCon->prepare($sql)) {
            //$stmt->bind_param("s", $chainid);
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
```

Comment: Did you try taking the `&` out of your code?

Comment: try adding a dot `$params[] .= &$branchid;` to both `$params[] .= &$chainid;`

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What error do you get?

Comment: plus, by looking at your question history, you seem to be posting the same question. One of which http://stackoverflow.com/q/31537654/ where you posted an answer?

Comment: so where are we with this and did my comment code work?

Comment: *I'm blowing bubbles, again*.

Comment: oh, and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I need to put a space character on the second filter because when I combined 2 filters the $sql was "AND a = aAND b=b"